# What does $1 do in jest config?

Tags: webpack, jestjs

The [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html) for using jest with webpack mentions this syntax: $1, and I haven't been able to figure out what it does. I'm working on two projects with the same aliases, but one works with jest config:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^myModule(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/react",
}
```

while one works with

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^myModule(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/react$1",
}
```

What does the $1 syntax do?

Comment: Haven't worked with it myself, but that appears to be a regular expression on the left side of the colon. The parens form a capture group (group 1). In the right side's expression The `$1` is replacement syntax to refer to capture group one. Had you two sets of parens on the left side, then you could refer to group one (`$1`) and group two (`$2`) in the replacement expression. Capture groups are numbered left-to-right, outermost to innermost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jest will take the key of the object, and wrap it with a `RegExp` object. so basically you are writing a regular expression string as the key. The $1..$9 in regular expressions are the capture groups captured for the match . A capture group is created by wrapping parenthesis around the pattern you want to "save".

```
 "^myModule(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/react$1"
```

so if you have an import of `myModule/SOMETHING` it will be mapped to:

```
myModule/SOMETHING => <rootDir>/src/components/react/SOMETHING"
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions